# How to set hide and show view using constraints like auto layout /StackView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a larger screen to design, it had plus button, for adding more fields in it. For example, i need to add 2 Email/Phone number, when i press plus button it will show one more textfield with in Email header as vice versa. If i use hide and show method programmatically, the rest of the space will be blank. For this i need to set constraint and setLayout for view. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to give idea so quick look at it.

Take a scroll view inside take one view that having all field your textfield like email and more text that you want.

Now design all field whatever you have to show.

add

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *ViewHeightConstraints;
```

for container view when you hide textfield just subtract height of all hideTextfield to  ViewHeightConstraints.

ok when you hide textfield do something like this:

```
 ViewHeightConstraints.constant = 0;
    _addressView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

ok when you Show textfield do something like this:

```
 ViewHeightConstraints.constant = 243;
        _addressView.hidden = NO;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

whenever you change constraints write this Everytime.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

for setting frame for your main View Set height constraints for MainView. i have done like this.

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *containerHeightConstraints;

_containerHeightConstraints.constant = _bottomView.frame.origin.y+_bottomViewHeight.constant;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: thank you for replying,i tried this. but the space is the same

Comment: See the Updated Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working some what fine. For example i have four views, i need to hide second view. it will hide and the first view height has been extended until the hidden second view space. when i press show button the  second view has appeared, and the first view goes to normal height. I Want, If i hide the second view, the rest of the below views are goes up and when i show the second view, its automatically goes down. Can you tell me the solution for this?

Comment: okk. when you hide second view then set frame for your whole View and similarly when you show again set frame for Main view. let me know if you haven't get idea

Comment: Sorry alot, May i know that what do you meant containerHeightConstraints? That four views of Super view or View3???

Comment: containerHeightConstraints is constraints for your view that is inside your scrollView. i suggest you that please read my Answer from first Line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a IBOutlet of the field height constraint for this.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *fieldConstraintHeight;
```

Now when you want to hide it use

```
fieldConstraintHeight.constant = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i tried this too. the hidden label/textfield space will be in space only. can you give any example or any link related to this.

Comment: @Ishwarya : follow Narendra Pandey's updated suggestion.